# Copying Sheets and cell references

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, cells, copy

Let's say I have "Sheet A" and "Sheet B" within the same workbook.

Sheet B has a cell that references Sheet "A" i.e. ='Sheet A '!Q20

I want to copy Sheet B and Create "Sheet C" in the same workbook and I want the cell reference (='Sheet A '!Q20) in Sheet C to now reference Sheet B.  i.e. ='Sheet B '!Q20.

When I copy sheet B and create Sheet C, the cell reference is still ='Sheet A '!Q20

I have seen solutions to similar issues but not when copying sheets within the same workbook.

TIA

Comment: I don't think you could do that in a single step as by definition, creating a copy means it copies what's in the original sheet. But if your formulas are all consistent, as in your question, then you could simply do a replace, searching for `Sheet A` and replacing with `Sheet B`. Just make sure that you're searching within the *sheet* and looking in *formulas*. You could likely make a simple vba macro that would combine the two actions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in **Sheet B**:

```
=INDIRECT("'Sheet "&CHAR(CODE(RIGHT(CELL("filename"),1))-1)&"'!A1")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a simple UDF, which returns a name of a worksheet whose position is moved by `ofs` from the current worksheet.

```
Function sh(ofs As Long) As String
    Dim cw As Long
    cw = Application.Caller.Parent.Index
    sh = Worksheets(cw + ofs).Name
End Function
```

The name of the previous worksheet will be `sh(-1)`, the next will be `sh(1)`.
Now you can refer to the cell `Q20` in the previous worksheet by a formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&sh(-1)&"'!Q20")
```

or

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(20,17,,,sh(-1)))
```